# Can I undo (cmd-Z) a git checkout file in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-checkout, code-editor

in Sublime Text, if the file was open in editor, I could Cmd-Z to a before-checkout file state after an accidental `git checkout [file]`.
Visual Studio Code, however, seems to hard-reset the changes without any way to get back. Is that so?

Comment: So are you saying that UNDO did not bring back the previous version before the accidental checkout?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, it did not :( quite a disappointment. Maybe this has to do with the editor git config or something.

Comment: This sucks...then you better be careful about nuking file versions.

Comment: I accidently nuked everything from the command line using `git checkout -- .` but a simple command z undo command got my data back on the files I opened